# How can I spoof the macOS version on macOS 13 or 14?

Tags: macos, mac, software

I tried to install Adobe Photoshop Elements on my MBP with macOS 14 Beta but it threw an error saying *"You must upgrade/update your system to install the product ... macOS 11.10 (Minimum required) (error code 195)."* I'm aware that apps may not work as expected on beta versions but would like to use it for one of my workflows. I could look into other solutions for getting it installed, but I'd like to how to spoof the MacOS version to get it installed.

I've tried editing the file `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` but have gotten the
"read only filesystem error."

Comment: Welcome to the exciting world of beta-testing; bringing you tomorrow's problems today! You should be prepared for things to go wrong; and when they do, have a stable OS to fall back on.

Comment: As a general rule, major OS betas shouldn't be used for production workflow. But you should make Adobe aware of the issue.

Comment: You could probably install Elements into a Ventura macOS environment, either another Mac or a VM, and then try using Migration Assistant to 'import' to the Sonoma beta.

Comment: Perhaps check the app's Info.plist file, to see if the limit is coded there?

Comment: @benwiggy Only `LSMinimumSystemVersion` is defined there. And the applications comes as an app, without an installer, so it seems to check the OS version on startup.